# SQL How to delete duplicate rows of a specific column and keep one

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, duplicates

The following code returns a list of duplicate rows of a specific column. In this case I am trying to find duplicates of university name. And my problem is how could I delete the duplicates and leave just one copy for each different university_name?

```
    Select * from `university` where `university_name` in ( select `university_name` from `university` group by `university_name` having count(*) > 1 )
```

This is the result:

[image]
Can you please explain I am very new to SQL! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: if you don't care which of the two you want to delete, group the entire result and select their IDs. Then delete the result. You could select the MAX(id) if you want to delete the second one.

Comment: If there are duplicates for a university_name, which row do you want to keep?

Comment: actually I might want to greater id to be deleted and keep the lowest id for future reference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) If you want to keep the row with the lowest id value:

```
DELETE a
FROM university a, university b
WHERE a.id > b.id
AND  b.university_name=a.university_name
```

2) If you want to keep the row with the highest id value:

```
DELETE a
FROM university a, university b
WHERE a.id < b.id
AND  b.university_name=a.university_name
```

Comment: I was not able to check if this works but thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELETE  u
FROM    university u
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT MIN(ID) ID, university_name
            FROM    university
            GROUP   BY university_name
        ) v ON  u.ID = v.ID AND
                u.university_name = v.university_name
WHERE   v.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the duplicates and keep the row with oldest id

```
DELETE a
FROM university a
JOIN university b ON a.university_name = b.university_name
WHERE a.id > b.id
```